# Do item bonuses stack?

Tags: darkville

For those who don't know it's a new addicting mobile/online game from qeep: http://www.qeep.net/blog_en/?p=834

I have a question about it - do the items you buy (like +2 attack, +5 attack, +4 defense) stack? I mean if I get +2 attack, and then later +4 attack, will I have +6, or just the last one (+4) ? If they don't stack, then I don't see any reason to buy older items...

Comment: This feels like it should be two different questions.  That would allow for much better question titles too.  Now that it has the bounty though it is going to make that more difficult.

Comment: well I'm more interested in getting an answer to the 1st question :) But any help on how to play this game effectively is welcome, because I there's no official faq/help about this game..

Comment: Hi Alex. Please limit yourself to one question at a time. I have removed the 2nd one from your post, since you have indicated the 1st is the main thing you care about. Feel free to open a new question about the 2nd topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the items don't get stacked. You will only be able to use the item with the highest rating, so it's advisable to complete tasks and repeat them even after completing to get more D$, then buy a decent item.

Answer (score 1):

The best items that you have will be used for your battles.